# pip install numpy doesn't work: "No matching distribution found"

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I am a newbie in Python. I installed Python 2.7.10 and it comes already with `pip`. I tried to run this command to download the NumPy library.

```
D:\workspace\python>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

But I got this error. How can I solve this?

I also want to know the difference between `easy_install` and `pip`.

Comment: are you behind a firewall? this command should work

Comment: what do you get for `pip -vvv install numpy`?

Comment: Checking with a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 docker container and fresh install of python 2.7 and python-pip -- on Linux `pip install numpy` requires python-dev/python-devel.  I wonder if that is also available on Windows.

Comment: Maybe look in here for a windows binary for numpy: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This goes through how to install numpy http://askubuntu.com/a/359627

Comment: Note that even if you do get past this error, you may also need to install a C++ compiler as it is required when installing Numpy from source. You can get the one for Python 2.7 here: http://aka.ms/vcpython27

Comment: @maxymoo I have a firewall but I set the proxy and confirmed to connect to the web.

Comment: @NightShadeQueen i got error. SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I already installed the C++ Compiler.

Comment: please [edit] your question to include the new information. Also, uh, can you reach https://pypi.python.org/pypi ?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Yes, I could reach there through browser. How can I check it through python ?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to install NumPy with pip now:

```
pip install numpy
```

Or with Conda:

```
conda install numpy
```

As for the difference between easy_install and pip, easy_install came first. People in the Python community had a difference of opinions and pip was born. Pip is basically just an alternative to easy_install. See the following for a good comparison of the two:

- https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/pip_easy_install.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link! Saved me the trouble of going via Anaconda as PIP just wouldn't work on my Windows.

Comment: I'm not sure installing from source is still the preferred way. It's easiest nowadays to install with pip or conda.

Comment: Yeah. This was the old answer. I updated it just now

Answer (score 0):

Two steps

1. install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266
2. `pip install lightfm --upgrade --ignore-installed scipy`

Comment: Please consider explaining _why_ these steps fix the problem.

Comment: is that worked for you let me know its not we will figure something else?

Comment: That link is outdated, since it only works for Python 2.7. (As you can see from the name of the file when you download it.)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and same error
In my case, the error occur due to slow internet connection
Its working after turn off then on internet next day.

Answer (score -2):

I encounter the same problem before and doing as below helped me solve it. Hope it will help you.
 Just simply run

> python pip install numpy --proxy (proxy server):(port number)

Comment: why add a proxy server, without any explanation to why?

Answer (score -5):

That happened to me when i tried to install without an internet connection...

Comment: please, avoid to answer like this